# How to eliminate recursion in Python function containing control flow

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, recursion, while-loop

I have a function of the form:

```
def my_func(my_list):
    for i, thing in enumerate(my_list):
        my_val = another_func(thing)

        if i == 0:
            # do some stuff
        else:
            if my_val == something:
                return my_func(my_list[:-1])
            # do some other stuff
```

The recursive part is getting called enough that I am getting a RecursionError, so I am trying to replace it with a while loop as explained [here](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html), but I can't work out how to reconcile this with the control flow statements in the function. Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew what these functions actually do

Comment: You have to provide all the `return` points in order to convert recursion to iterative.

Comment: Check my answer once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_func(my_list):
    run = True
    while run:
        for i, thing in enumerate(my_list):
            my_val = another_func(thing)

            if i == 0:
                # do some stuff
            else:
                if my_val == something:
                    my_list = my_list[:-1]
                    break
                # do some other stuff
```

This is an iterative method.

## Decorator

```
class TailCall(object):
    def __init__(self, __function__):
        self.__function__ = __function__
        self.args = None
        self.kwargs = None
        self.has_params = False

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.has_params = True
        return self

    def __handle__(self):
        if not self.has_params:
            raise TypeError
        if type(self.__function__) is TailCaller:
            return self.__function__.call(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self.__function__(*self.args, **self.kwargs)


class TailCaller(object):
    def __init__(self, call):
        self.call = call

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ret = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
        while type(ret) is TailCall:
            ret = ret.__handle__()
        return ret

@TailCaller
def factorial(n, prev=1):
    if n < 2:
        return prev
    return TailCall(factorial)(n-1, n * prev)
```

To use this decorator simply wrap your function with `@TailCaller` decorator and return `TailCall` instance initialized with required params.

I'd like to say thank you for inspiration to **@o2genum** and to **Kyle Miller** who wrote [an excellent article about this problem](http://www.kylem.net/programming/tailcall.html).

Despite how good is to remove this limitation, probably, you have to be
aware of [why this feature is not officially supported](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

Answer (score 2):

There may be a good exact answer, but the most general (or maybe quick-and-dirty) way to switch from recursion to iteration is to [manage the stack yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159777/633969). Just do manually what programming language does implicitly and have your own unlimited stack.

In this particular case there is [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). You see, `my_func` recursive call result is not used by the caller in any way, it is immediately returned. What happens in the end is that the deepest recursive call's result bubbles up and is being returned as it is. This is what makes @outoftime's solution possible. We are only interested in into-recursion pass, as the return-from-recursion pass is trivial. So the into-recursion pass is replaced with iterations.